# How can I isolate four bits from an integer and reduce them to the lowest possible number?

Tags: c#, vb.net, algorithm, binary

I have the following function:

```
int Extract(int fullNumner, int fourBitMask)
{
     var filteredNumber=fullNumber & fourBitMask;
     var reducedNumber=...
     return reducedNumber;
 }
```

What I want to achieve is this (numbers represented in binary with dashes for readability):

Extract(1001-1100-0000,1111-0000-0000)=1001

Extract(1001-1100-0000,1111-000)=1100

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is valid syntax in c#, but you can do something like this:

```
// check whether the LSB is 1
while ((fourBitMask & 1) == 0)
{
// If not, then right shift by 1.
    fourBitMask >> 1;
    reducedNumber >> 1;
}
```

Comment: except that == has a higher precedende than & so you need `while ((fourBitMask & 1) == 0)`

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I have understood you correctly and your mask should always be on a 4 bit nibble boundary. In that case this should work:

```
static int Extract(int fullNumner, int fourBitMask)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * 2; i++) 
    {
        int result = ((fullNumner & fourBitMask) & 0xF);
        if (result != 0)
            return result;
        fullNumner >>= 4;
        fourBitMask >>= 4;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Helped on the way by Alex and user1990169 I cooked up my own solution (in VB) using extensions. All the extensions are unit test tested. As a bonus the extracted bits are not restricted to four: any mask with one ore more consecutive ones will be accepted.

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Extracts the bits from the enumValue by applying the mask and then removing all trailing zeroes.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="enumValue"></param>
    ''' <param name="mask">A binary number that must solely consist of a number of consecutive ones, followed by zero or more zeroes.</param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks>The return value will have as many bits as there were consecutive ones in the mask.</remarks>'
    <Extension>
    Public Function ExtractBits(enumValue As Integer, mask As Integer) As Integer
        Dim maskedValue = (enumValue And mask)

        Dim maskLength = mask.CountSetBits(mustBeConsecutive:=True)
        Dim highestSetBit = maskedValue.GetHighestSetBit
        Dim extractedValue = maskedValue >> (highestSetBit - maskLength + 1)

        Return extractedValue
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns the number of set bits in an integer
    ''' </summary>>'
    <Extension>
    Public Function CountSetBits(value As Integer, Optional mustBeConsecutive As Boolean = False) As Integer
        Dim count As Integer
        Dim setBitFound As Boolean
        Dim zeroAfterSetBitFound As Boolean
        Do While value > 0
            If (value And 1) = 1 Then
                If zeroAfterSetBitFound AndAlso mustBeConsecutive Then
                    Throw New ArgumentException(String.Format("The value {0} does not contain solely consecutve ones. Set the mustBeConsecutive parameter to'False' to prevent this exception.",
                                                              Convert.ToString(value, 2)))
                End If
                setBitFound = True
                count += 1
            Else
                If setBitFound Then zeroAfterSetBitFound = True
            End If
            value >>= 1
        Loop

        Return count
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns the largest set bit as the exponent that must be set on 2 to get the number that corresponds with the highest set bit.
    ''' </summary>'
    <Extension>
    Public Function GetHighestSetBit(value As Integer) As Integer
        Dim largestMultipleOfTwo As Integer
        value >>= 1
        Do While value > 0
            largestMultipleOfTwo += 1
            value >>= 1
        Loop
        Return largestMultipleOfTwo
    End Function
```